# Vuejs Filter add Span

Tags: vue.js

I'm filtering with vuejs, only the output I want is written in the ".00" span in the comma. how can i do it?

html

1.500 ,00

component

```
<p class="amount">{{ 1500 | toTL }}</p>
```

filter

```
Vue.filter('toTL', function (value) {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat('tr-TR', { currency: 'TRY', minimumFractionDigits: 2}).format(value);
});
```

output

```
1.500,00
```

Comment: So, exactly what do you want to do? Are you getting1500,00 from API and you want 1500 in the <p> and withing that the ,00 in the span?

Comment: I want something like,I want the comma separated field to be written as a span in p.

Answer (score 0):

I declared you value in the data() function like so :

```
data () {
    return {
        number: '1500,00',
        newNumber: [],
    }
},
```

What I did to make this work is make a created function like so :

```
created() {
    this.newNumber = this.number.split(',')
},
```

Then, in the frontend (your p and span) :

```
<p>{{ newNumber[0] }}<span>,{{newNumber[1]}}</span></p>
```

What I did is turn a value into an array by using the split() function.

There is probably a way better solution but this is what I came up with in a short amount of time, I hope it helps.

Comment: like this, when I send filter (1500), the data returned to me is "1.500.00". I want to add a new span after this value, comma and comma. You completely misunderstood.

Comment: Well, yeah. I asked for clarification but I didnt recieve any new information. But still, you could split your returned value (1500,00) to a new array and return that.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16233919/17426666) new style